# Correct and proper binding of a control/UIElement visibility to Property MVVM C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I'm quite new to MVVM, and I've been constructing my ViewModels. I have a ViewModel which contains an `ICommand`, which is then bound to in my View by a command button. The `ICommand` causes a procedure to be invoked on my ViewModel which then invokes a further large slow procedure. While this procedure is happening I want to make a control/`UIElement`'s visibility to become visible and then hidden after the procedure has finished (I intend to bind a label and indeterminate progress bar's visibility)

For example, in my view model I have

```
public void calledFromCommandButton() {
RaisePropertyChange("Starting");
superLongProcedure();
RaisePropertyChange("Finished");

}
```

This just feels a bit silly though, having to raise 2 different property changes and hence, I presume I'm doing it all wrong. I think I could do it with one property change along with a convertor?

So, what is the proper and correct method to bind UIElement visibilities to property change events?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: What are "Starting" and "Finished" properties good for? Have one bool property IsBusy and then you can use Visibility="{Binding Path=IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}}"

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using a single `boolean` property (IsWorking or something) and then using the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to show and hide the button.  So, it would look something like:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
       <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TrueToVisibleConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
     ...
    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Visiblity="{Binding IsWorking, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisibleConverter}}"/>
     ...
</Window/>
```

Comment: So you mean have something like

            `_bIsBusy = true;
            PropertyHasChanged("IsBusy");
            DO CALCULATION
            _bIsBusy = false;
            PropertyHasChanged("IsBusy");

Then have 

        public Visibility IsBusy
        {

            get {

                return _bIsBusy ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden; 
            
            }

        }
`
Problem is that, the UI doesn't get updated, until after the calculation, by which time the control is invisible again.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you not want to use a `BackgroundWorker`, or do you not want to do the work on a background thread?  If you are not going to do the work on a background thread, then the UI will never update until after the work is complete because the UI thread will be blocked.  No way around that.  If you just don't want to use the `BackgroundWorker`, there are alternatives for doing the work asynchronously - take a look at `Task` if you are using >= .NET 4.